# AngularJs: controller is called twice by using $routeProvider

Tags: controller, angularjs

Module routes:

```
var switchModule = angular.module('switchModule', []);

switchModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/build-content', {templateUrl: 'build-content.html', controller: BuildInfoController});
}]);
```

Controller:

```
function BuildInfoController($http, $scope){
    alert("hello");
}
```

Html:

```
<html ng-app="switchModule">
...
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#build-content"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
</body>
...
```

Each time when i click the hyperlink '', the 'BuildInfoController' will be called twice. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Does build-content.html have `ng-controller="BuildInfoController"?  If so, try removing that.

Comment: No such an ng-controller like you said. Anyway, thanks a lot. I've already fixed it by using camus's solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combating AngularJS executing controller twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but in my case the controller is being fired only on page refresh.  If I navigate to the page from a link the controller only fires once, as expected.  However if I refresh the page, it fires twice.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had the same problem , and it seems there is a stupid bug with routing. There is some kind of redirection going on.

to fix it , i just added a slash in the href , like :

```
<li><a href="#/build-content/"></a></li>
```

I hope it will fix things for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This weird problem almost killed me last night. ^_^

Comment: Nice one @mpm, you saved me a lot of time debugging

Comment: This solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535724/1387163 helps me to solve the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was about loosing hope. Is this a known bug? I have a bunch of similar controllers and calls and there is only one I need to add a slash at the end of the URL. Happens only when called via ng-href not when the route is called directly.

Comment: thats not solve my problem.. my app is start and controller hit two time i am not click on any link..

Comment: had same problem and adding a slash at the end solved my problem too. I was using angular-route.js ver 1.2.25

Comment: You can read why this is happening here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes  and about the urlmatcher here. https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

Answer (score 72):

I had face same issue today. I had added controller name in my $routeProvider and also in my html.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'html/views/log-in.html'
     })
```

and in my view as

```
<div class="personalDetails" ng-controller="LoginController"> </div>
```

You can remove controller name either from your view or from your routeprovider.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening! Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

I've had a similar problem.  I found adding a trailing slash in the route but not in the link worked as expected.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/build-content/',...);
```

With this markup

```
<li><a href="/build-content">Content</a></li>
```

And then AngularJS will correct the URL in the browser to what is defined in the $routeProvider.

Bizarrely the opposite seems to work too with a trailing slash in the link and not in the route.  It seems as long as the trailing slashes *don't* match the resolves and controller won't be called twice!

Comment: You just saved my weekend!

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. We noticed exactly the same thing. We were careful to keep the routes and the hrefs consistent in terms of trailing slashes and could not get it to work. It was only once we followed your advice and made sure that they were different that it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Mine was a case of having 2 ng-view directives. I tried to wrap it, but unintentionally duplicated it:

```
<div class="ng-view">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Removed the wrapper, fixed it.

Comment: That happened to me before where I had two completely different app section in my index.html, one for my login/registration and another one for the app itself, both containing the ng-view.

Comment: @DominicGoulet I have two different ng-view in my index.html. so the controllers are being called twice.Is there any solution for that except removing ng-views. I don't want remove those 2 ng-views.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `ng-controller` directive from your template pages if exists .

Comment: It works!. May I know the reason, why should we remove ng-controller

Comment: Understood,      already added in when('/trending/', {
                templateUrl: "./templates/trending.html", controller: 'TrendingController'            }) , now it should not be in template

Comment: Thanks you! I never thought that!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and found that if you bootstrapped you angular two time you can have same error.

In my case I had `<body ng-app>` but also `angular.bootstrap(document,['app'])` and that caused double initialization of controllers.

Hope this can save some time to someone.

Answer (score 1):

A controller can be added to more than one element of the DOM, so this problem can occur if this has been done e.g. :

```
  <div id="myDiv1" ng-controller="myController" ....></div>
  ....
  <div id="myDiv2" ng-controller="myController" ....></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had declaration of SomeController for each view partial in a single state.
That caused duplicate event firing.

```
 .state('chat', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/chat_wv1.html',
                    controller: 'ChatController'
                },
                'form@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/chat_wv_placeholder.html',
                    controller: 'ViewController'
                },
                'sidePanel@': {
                     templateUrl: 'views/sidePanel_wv.html'
                     /* removing this part solved my issue*/
                     /*controller: 'ChatController'*/
                }

            }
        })
```

Hope this helps some  one else.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem with a customDirective and unitentionally duplicated my controller.

```
<html>
   <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyDirectiveCtrl">
      <my-directive></my-directive>
   </body>
</html>

angular.directive('myDirectivie', [function() {
   return {
         restrict: 'E',
         controller: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',

         ...

   }
}]);
```

I resolved it by removing ng-controller tag at body level

Answer (score 0):

its because you have multiple ui-view