# AngularJS ng-click fires twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-click and it fires twice when I apply it to SPAN tag.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="regApp" ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl" data-ng-init="GetEventDetail()" ng-show="data.EventName">

    <h2>Registration for {{data.EventName}}</h2>
    <span class="btn" id="btnSave" ng-click="PostRegistration()">Save </span>

</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
var app = angular.module('regApp', ['ui']);

app.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.PostRegistration = function () {
    alert('click '); <--- fires twice
    /// some code here -- 
};
```

It should only fire once. How I can find why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The code you've provided does not fire the event twice:

http://jsfiddle.net/kNL6E/ (click `Save`)

Perhaps you included Angular twice?  If you do that, you'll get two alerts, demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kNL6E/1/

Comment: yup. that was it. (kicking myself)

Comment: This (inadvertantly including angular.js twice) will wreak all kinds of havoc if model attributes are $watched... Easy to do, too, depending on your dependent lib pipeline.

Comment: I do not see the difference between the code above. How did you included Angular twice?

Comment: Don't forget, jquery/angular.element selections can return multiple items, so what looks like one trigger may in fact be a trigger for each element in the set.

Comment: @windchime, in the second fiddle, angular is included under "Frameworks & Extensions" and a second time under "External Resources"

Comment: Had the problem when I had the ng-click set at the label level and I solved it by moving to the <input/> level. Here more info of why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689531/angular-js-ng-click-events-on-labels-are-firing-twice

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem, but could not find where I included Angular twice in my files.

I was using an ajax calls to load specific form layouts, so I need to use `$compile` to activate Angular on the inserted DOM. However, I was using `$compile` on my directive `$element` which has a controller attached. Turns out this "includes" the controller twice, causing two triggers with `ng-click` or `ng-submit`.

I fixed this by using `$compile` directly on the inserted DOM instead of my directive `$element`.

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I can't remember the exact code I was using before, but I came up with something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/noodle_wave/esoox41v/

Comment: Encountering this years later on a legacy project!   What do you mean by directly on the inserted DOM? Doesn't Angular register the first dom element anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Same problem using

```
<a ng-click="fn()"></a>
```

fn was called twice

Using a button fixed it :

```
<button ng-click="fn()"></button>
```

Comment: The closing bracket on the first code sample should be </a> shouldn't it?

Answer (score 9):

This is probably obscure, but I had `ng-click` firing twice because I had BrowserSync running, which would mirror my inputs into a tab that I had open in another window, thus doubling up all my clicks. To resolve, I disabled “ghostMode”: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

Comment: thank you very much, that was exactly my problem too.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by removing my ngsubmit handler as I don't have a need for it. I'm monitoring on change events and using SignalR to update the screen in near real-time.

I was also in  a form and the [AngularJS docs for ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) states:

> Warning: Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the `ngClick` and `ngSubmit` handlers together. See the form [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action) for a detailed discussion of when `ngSubmit` may be triggered.

Answer (score 7):

In case of somebody having the same issue:
This was my problem:

```
<a type="submit" ng-click="login()">submit login<a>
```

Both, the `type="submit"` and the `ng-click="login()"`triggered the login()-method in my controller.

So just use either the type=submit or the ng-click directive

Answer (score 5):

If other answers don't help, make sure that AngularJS profiling is disabled in Batarang (if you have it installed of course).

This was making ng-click to fire twice for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

elements wrapped one another, and this can cause trigger event twice or more.

So i used a simple CSS trick for this solution :

```
.off{
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

and apply it to an element correspond to click event.

Answer (score 4):

You might have a ng-click inside a form container using a ng-submit. In that case, add type="button" to all your  using ng-click.

Answer (score 3):

I got it when I accidently called $compile for the dynamically added elements several times in the cycle, instead of just once. Compiling just once removed this effect.

Answer (score 2):

was facing same issue. 
Find out they were using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js version and i switch it to latest 1.4.5 version and it just worked.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js

```js
var app = angular.module('regApp', []);

app.controller('RegistrationCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http ) {
  $scope.PostRegistration = function() {
    alert('click '); // <--- fires twice
    /// some code here -- 
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="regApp" ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl">
  <h2 >Registration for {{data.EventName}}</h2>
  <span ng-click="PostRegistration()" class="btn" id="btnSave">Save </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed **<button ng-click='clickHandler()'>** to **<a ng-click='clickHandler()'>** and now event fires only once

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue when dynamically injecting partial views in my SPA(Single Page Applications).The way I solved it was to store the content of my div in a local variable like this:

```
var html = $("#leftContainer").html();
```

Then empty out the div and reset its content like this:

```
$("#leftContainer").empty();
$("#leftContainer").append(html);
```

Now you can add any additional html you have received from an AJAX call or dynamically constructed and lastly remember to re-compile your HTML to make it bound to angular:

```
var entities = $("#entitiesContainer");

var entity = "<div><a href='#' ng-click='Left(" + entityId + ")'>&nbsp;" + entityName + "</a><div>"
entities.append(entity);

var leftContainer = angular.element(document.getElementById("entitiesContainer"));

$compile(leftContainer)($scope);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a dummy and had this:

```
<li data-shape="amethyst" ng-click="toggleGem('amethyst')">
    <label></label>
    <i class="amethyst"></i>Amethyst
    <input type="checkbox" name="gem_type" id="gem-amethyst" value="amethyst" />
</li>
```

The click event was triggering twice. I moved the ng-click to the label element and it's working as expected.

```
<li data-shape="amethyst">
    <label ng-click="toggleGem('amethyst')"></label>
    <i class="amethyst"></i>Amethyst
    <input type="checkbox" name="gem_type" id="gem-amethyst" value="amethyst" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This situation may be caused by lacking the ngTouch in Angular.

Event if the ngTouch is loaded, the [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6251) in ngTouch and ngClick before Angular 1.5.0 may occur. It results from the ngClick being triggered by `pointerup` and `mouseUp` in Chrome for Desktop on device toolbar or mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this as well.

```
<button style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="'{{vm.delete()}}'">
```

Thats not how you call ng-click, but no errors were thrown and the function calls still worked.

```
<button style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.delete()">
```

Is correct and will then only be called once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was the reason this happened, but I had to use `event.stopPropagation();` inner my JavaScript function.

HTML

```
<button class="button" ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function save(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **I have handled it by following code**

HTML :

```
<div>
    <ui>
        <li>
            <button class="Button" ng-disabled="self.desableSubmitButton" ng- 
            click="self.SubmitClick($event)">Submit</button>
        </li>
    </ui> 
</div>
```

Angular 1.0 Controller :

```
_self.SubmitClick = function(event){   
     _self.desableSubmitButton = true; //disable submit button
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();

     setTimeout(funtion() {
       _self.desableSubmitButton = false; //enable submit button after timeout
           if(_self.$scope.$$phase != '$apply' || _self.$scope.$$phase != '$digest'){
             _self.$scope.$digest();
             }
      }, 1000);//other Code logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case: I used ng-click event on my custom custom angular checkbox component. So just providing a method binding for custom component did the trick.

Before:
`<mono-checkbox-ng ng-click="vm.onSelectAllClicked()">`

After:
`<mono-checkbox-ng on-changed="vm.onSelectAllClicked()">`