# Angular.js ng-click events on labels are firing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following code using angular.js

Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/i4MAzs

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  Try clicking on the labels. <br/>
  <label>
    Value1: <input type="checkbox" ng-checked='value1' ng-click='toggleValue1()'>
  </label> <br/>
  <label ng-click='toggleValue2()'>
    Value2: <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="value2">
  </label> <br/>
  <tt>value1 = {{value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>value2 = {{value2}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>fire_count = {{fire_count}}</tt>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = true;
  $scope.value2 = 'YES'
  $scope.fire_count = 0;

  $scope.toggleValue1 = function(){
    $scope.value1 = !$scope.value1;
    $scope.fire_count++;
    console.log("Clicked!");
  }

  $scope.toggleValue2 = function(){
    $scope.value2 = !$scope.value2;
    $scope.fire_count++;
    console.log("Clicked!");
  }
}
```

The click event will fire twice when you click on the 'Value2' label.  This only happens when ng-click is attached to the label.  When it's attached to the input element everything works as expected.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: It's very weird, if you change "label" to "div" it works properly

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185362/3093703

Also, I've edited your plnkr to show the event target:

http://plnkr.co/edit/73aslwHnwVcTd2fxSJ0f?p=preview

Both the input and label elements are receiving the event.

To avoid this, you can check the tag name of the event target before performing any action.

**Edit**

As to why this is:
the label is actually tied to the input element in a way the div's or other elements would not be. The input is called the label's [labeled control](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#labeled-control).

When you trigger an action on a label, that action is also run on the labeled control:

> For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user