# Angular. Send http requests after selecting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background:** 
I’m working on an angular app that displays a list of articles. The list can be modified by various settings. One such setting is the sources of these articles. Think of a source as a news agency: an article originates from a particular source:

[image]

So when a user clicks on the "Sources" link, a dropdown menu should appear which contains a list of the sources. The user can select any combination of these sources. There are also a "Select all" and "Clear all" buttons to either select all the sources or deselect them all:

[image]

**Problem:** 
So every time a user selects or deselects a source, an http request should be sent to the server, and the list of the articles should be updated.

My problem is, I am not sure how to call the function that will send an http request (in the code snippets below it's called `updateArticleList()`).

1) If I bind the function to `ng-click` and set it on the `label` tag:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="source in sources">
    <label ng-click="updateArticleList()">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.selected">
      {{source.title}}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

then a click on the label triggers the function twice (once for `label`, and, apparently, once for `input`). Not good.

2) If I bind the function to `ng-change` on the `input` tag:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="source in sources">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.selected"
       ng-change="updateArticleList()">
      {{source.title}}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

then once I click on "Select all" or "Clear" buttons, this will change the state of all the checkboxes and send a lot of http requests. Not good either.

Right now, I am trying to solve this using `setTimeout` to filter out a burst of calls to the function to one, like so (example for calling the function through ng-click):

```
    var requestAllowed = true;

    var debounceRequests = function(){
      requestAllowed = false;
      setTimeout(function(){
        requestAllowed = true; 
      }, 5);
    };

    scope.updateArticleList = function(){
      if (requestAllowed === true){
        // prevent the second call to the function from ng-click
        debounceRequests();
        // also, give time for the input to register ng-click on the label
        setTimeout(function(){
             // finally, send an http request
             getArticles();
        }, 5);
      }
    };
```

But this looks dirty.

So, my question is, what would be a good way to make http requests in this situation?

*Preferably, without using extra js libraries.*

==================

**UPDATED:**

Here's the function that is triggered by "Select All":

```
    scope.selectAllSources = function(){
      scope.sources.forEach(function(source){
        source.selected = true;
      });
      scope.updateArticleList();
    };
```

Comment: Good question: well-presented objective and problem

Comment: @NewDev is right, can you post your selectAll code?

Comment: @azangru, do you need to submit only the changed sources, or just resubmit all the selected ones (even if only 1 additional source was selected)?

Comment: @NewDev: That is something I am still not quite sure about. At the moment, I am resubmitting all the list of the sources, indicating which of them are selected (`selected=true`) and which are not. Must be a waste of bandwidth :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ng-change`.

`ng-change` only fires when the input is changing the model - not the other way around. Your `selectAll` should change the model. I'm guessing that you are doing the "select all" differently.

```
$scope.selectAll = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sources.length; i++) {
    $scope.sources[i].selected = true; // this does not fire `ng-change`
  }

  $scope.updateArticleList();
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on the OP's comment about submitting all the sources on every change, the following is a more complete conceptual example of how this could be achieved:

```
<li ng-repeat="source in sources">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.selected" ng-change="updateArticleList()">
      {{source.title}}
   </label>
</li>
<button ng-click="selectAll()">select all</button>
```

Comment: That's interesting. I guess I haven't investigated the ng-change option that closely. I'll go and check whether it's giving me the problem that I tought it will give me or whether it was all my imagination.

Comment: Hey, you are right. Looks like I've been worrying too much, and doing something like `$scope.sources[i].selected = true;` in the directive will not trigger `ng-change`. That's awesome! Let me re-write my directive and see if anything breaks :-)

Comment: Yay! Works like a charm.

Comment: @azangru, yes, this is "by design". `ng-change` was meant to update the controller of the change. The controller doesn't need an additional trigger if it itself changes the model values.

Answer (score 1):

I liked your first solution better and after exploring around I remembered a similar question: [Angular.js ng-click events on labels are firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689531/angular-js-ng-click-events-on-labels-are-firing-twice)

So a solution you can do is to check the event element and make sure the tag is right.

```
    $scope.updateArticleList = function(event){
        if(event.toElement.tagName == 'LABEL'){
            //run code
        }
    };
```

HTML

```
<label ng-click="updateArticleList($event)">
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p48q63j/

Comment: Very simple and clean - great

Comment: @BenDiamant - not at all clean! Mathew, your controller is now aware of the View - it should be View-agnostic

Comment: @NewDev You're being too strict about it, if its a repetetive logic do it in a directive (an option for approval) but if not controller is ok.

Comment: @BenDiamant, No no... This is indicative of the wrong thinking about MVVM more so than a particular instance of being aware of the View. Can't be too strict about that

Comment: I've chosen @NewDev’s answer, but I just wanted to say thank you for showing another interesting approach to this problem.

Comment: No worries, I like his answer better as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="source in sources">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.selected"
       ng-change="updateArticleList(source.selected)">
      {{source.title}}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller;
for individual selection....

```
$scope.updateArticleList=function(checked)
{
    if(checked==true)
    {
      //Call to service
    }
}
```

for selecteAll(button/Link) there are multiples ways to go with....

```
    $scope.selectAll = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.sources,function(source,$index){
       // model value will be true for all sources....
       //Call to service
    });
    };
```