# How to prevent ng-click's triggering twice on label tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Angular's ng-click gets triggered twice when I click label which has input inside in it. I've tried `$event.stopPropagation();` but didn't work. How do I solve this?

I've checked this question also:
[Angular.js ng-click events on labels are firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689531/angular-js-ng-click-events-on-labels-are-firing-twice)

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in model.data">
  <form role="form" name="selectForm" novalidate>
    <label ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); updateSelected();">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chechkedSkins[item.id]" />
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `$event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @ClaudioBredfeldt preventDefault breaks more mate, Adrian solved my problem, check the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ng-change="updateSelected"`

Use this only on the input since the change is triggered even if you click the label.

Comment: dang that stinks. ng-click is the only thing that works to hit my function. When I use ng-change, it doesn't work. Im tired of angularjs being so broken.

Answer (score 6):

Well thats because `label` is the parent or container for the `checkbox`, so the `click` handler is attached to the complete container in your case, thereby whenever either `label` or `checkbox` is clicked, event is triggered.

---

**Whats wrong with your approach:**

- Firstly never insert the input tags inside the label, thats not a good way to construct markup in html.In `Angular.js` this behaviour causes the click event to be triggered for both the tags. so to add a binding between `input` tag & `label` use the `for` attribute of label.
- Using `$event.stopPropagation()` inside label actually stops all events from propagating/boiling to the top of the DOM from the label. this will not serve any purpose because the event would still propagate to the input  with in the label.

I hope you can visualise what i'm saying.

**What I have done:**

- Use `for` attribute to bind the `input` to the label & add a `click` event to prevent the default functionality.
- Add the click handler to the respective `input` tag & not the `label`

  `<label for="username" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();">Click me</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" ng-click="updateSelected();">`

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/b0sv5drn/)

This way you don't have to worry about any conflicts in event handling,also its neat way to maintain the HTML code :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version of Angular Material 1.0.3 and still having this issue when clicking on labels that are configured as buttons on Android.  I don't have the problem on IOS or the browser (cordova app).  The following resolved it for me.

my html:

```
 <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.goAbout()">About</label>
```

my controller:

```
 vm.goAbout = debounceFn(function(){
        //show dialog here, and now it only pops up once
    }, 250, false);
```

The debounce function:

```
function debounceFn(func, wait, immediate){
       var timeout;
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if(!immediate) {
                deferred.resolve(func.apply(context, args));
                deferred = $q.defer();
              }
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            if ( timeout ) {
              $timeout.cancel(timeout);
            }
            timeout = $timeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) {
              deferred.resolve(func.apply(context,args));
              deferred = $q.defer();
            }
            return deferred.promise;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response mate (: