# angular-ui-tree two events instead of one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I'm sure it is pretty simple question, but I can't find answer. I use pretty common pattern for creating tree. I need to know if user click parent node or child node. Everything works fine if I click parent node. But if I click child node, the callback function calls two times - first from child node, second from parent node. Could somebody explain me why? Thank you.

```
<div id="groups-tree" class="col-sm-4">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
        <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="node.nodes && node.nodes.length > 0"
               ng-click="selected(node)" data-nodrag>
                <span class="glyphicon"
                      ng-class="{
    'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed,
    'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed
}"></span>
            </a>
            {{node.title}}
        </div>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
            <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"
                ng-click="selected(node)"*@ data-nodrag>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div ui-tree id="tree-root">
                <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="data" data-nodrag>
                    <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"
                        ng-click="selected(node)"></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330112/how-to-prevent-ng-clicks-triggering-twice-on-label-tag). The angular-ui-tree is sequence of enclosed elements. So I should stop propagate the event from child element to parent element.