# ng-click fires function twice angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have used ng-click in many html files but in all that html ng-click is working fine but in case of my filter.html ng-click fires function two times i goggled and found link but i am not able to under stand that .

Here is the link :-

[AngularJS ng-click fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709297/angualrjs-ng-click-fires-twice)

So here i am posting my index.html :-

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>e-commerce</title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
 src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>



<script src="lib/ionic-zoom-view/dist/ionic-zoom-view.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- your app's js -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">



<script
 src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script -->
<!--  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> -->
<script
<!--  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script> -->
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">



<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/checklist-model.js"></script>

<!-- controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/home-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ionic-ratings.js"></script>

<script src="lib/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/angular-swiper/dist/angular-swiper.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

when ever i am trying to call openPopover($event) function it fires two times but when i comment the below mentioned lines in index.html the the openPopover($event) trigers only one time but my smooth loader stops working .

lines :-

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

This thing really driving me crazy ..Any help will be greatly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Could you create a plunkr?

Comment: Could you update your post and include your `$stateProvider` configuration and the includes in the index html?

Comment: Please create a demo that replicates this problem

Comment: Thanks for your replies but i havn't made plunker yet..so i just tried but do not know how to make it work .but i put my whole used code inside this plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mjgpcwwpny89jEwwsoV1?p=preview

Comment: perhaps you included angular twice (like the guy in the answer you posted). Remember ionic already includes angular, so if you are also including an standalone angular lib, there will be an issue.

Comment: Can you please point that issue in code , where i added it from myself,Thanks

Comment: What if you move the ng-click to the child `<a>`?