# Angular form double posting (not having another ng-controller in the html)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this bites me too, like [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice) I have a simple ng-form (:
cleared for bravity) in a partial:

```
<form ng-submit="functionName()">


                   <input type="text" class="postField" ng-model="model.text" required ng-maxlength=200 />
            <button class="postBT" ng-click="functionName()" ng-class="BToverclass" ng-mouseover="BToverclass = 'overShadow'" ng-mouseleave="BToverclass=''">Post</button>
            </div>

            </form>
```

for some reason every form submit, we get 2 posts to the controller, with all the data doubled. I checked and the specific controller doesn't appear in the html, but only in the route. Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both an `ng-click()` calling `functionName()` and a call to it from `ng-submit`.  Each results in a call to your function.  You only want the submit one.

FYI, you also have a `</div>` with no opening `<div>` for it to close.

Here's working code:

```
  <form ng-submit="functionName()">
      <input type="text" class="postField" ng-model="model.text" required ng-maxlength=200 />
      <button class="postBT" ng-class="BToverclass" ng-mouseover="BToverclass = 'overShadow'" ng-mouseleave="BToverclass=''">Post</button>

   </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it tomorrow.  and if the form has another button to submit in another option(to the same controller)?, should I remove ```ng-submit```or would ng-submit (since it's the same function) take care of both input fields and buttons (one for uploading files..)?

Comment: The ng-submit will handle all the form elements in the same way submit does in traditional html.  You probably want to keep the ng-submit.  For the file upload you might want to check out ngUpload:  http://twilson63.github.io/ngUpload/