# Angular factory always called twice

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a REST service from angular and it always calls the factory twice.  Here is the factory code.

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = '/api';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getMyItems = function () {            
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/MyItems');
    };

    return dataFactory;
} ]);
```

It's called from the controller here

```
app.controller('MyItemsController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory',
    function ($scope, dataFactory) {            
        $scope.myItems;

        getItems();

        function getItems() {

            dataFactory.getMyItems()
                .success(function (itemsData) {
                    $scope.myItems = itemsData;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load items data: ' + error.message;
                });
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: This can happen if your controller is being instantiated twice. Put a console.log as first line in the controller function and see console output.

Comment: @Chandermani The controller is being instantiated twice.  I can't find where, it's only referenced once in the view with `data-ng-controller="MyItemsController"`

Comment: Check your routeProvider config. Search for string `MyItemsController`

Comment: @Chandermani  It's in the routeProvider for that partial page.  Does that instantiate it?  Should I remove it from there or the partial page `data-ng-controller`?

Comment: @Chandermani  I removed it from the routeProvider and it doesn't call twice.  When I removed it from the view `data-ng-controller` it still called twice.  What's the proper practice?

Comment: There is nothing like best practice here. Anywhere you put it should get called once only. Maybe something is causing the route change twice.

Comment: Also check if you are not including `angular.js` and `<controller.js>` files twice in `index.html`. I once had this problem.

Comment: I have `ng-controller="my-controller"` in my `body` tag. And a service method was called 4 or 5 times randomly. If I leave out `ng-controller` it is called 0 times. So this is bugging me. There is only one place ng-controller is set.

Comment: My issue was that I called a service method in `ng-show="mymethod()"` This called the method multiple times.

Comment: May be you have a duplicate controller name

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem as yours where the controller in general was called twice; hence, the factory will be called twice.

**But after looking at this solution:** 
[Combating AngularJS executing controller twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice)

**Step 1:**

Make sure you are adding the service and controller in your (main layout view) only once.

Example:

*index.html*

```
  <script src="../MyItemsController.js"></script>
  <script src="../MyItemsService.js"></script>
```

***If the problem still persists after doing step 1 go to step 2***

---

**Step 2:**

***There are two ways to do it:-***

**1. Either keep the controller in your view (ng-controller), and remove it from your config route like this:**

*route config (usually, app.js):*

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/',
               { 
                   templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
                   //Remove controller from here
               });
}]);
```

*home.html*

```
 <!-- Add the ng-controller in your view -->
    <div ng-controller="MyItemsController">
        <!-- Your stuff -->
    </div>
```

**2. Or keep the controller in your config route, and remove ng-controller
    from view like this:**

*route config (usually, app.js):*

```
  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/',
               { 
                   templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                   controller: 'MyItemsController' //Add the controller here

               });
}]);
```

*home.html*

```
 <!-- Remove the ng-controller in your view -->
    <div>
        <!-- Your stuff -->
    </div>
```

**Note:  The above solution works with ui router as well.**

Comment: Step 2, bless you.  Switching over from a website to a web app left ng-controllers all over my views when my router was already handling that and I totally thought I had already removed them during the migration.  Thank you!