# Node.js: POST request sent twice by system

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I send JSON POST data via a form in a MEAN environment to my server. On the server side, I process the data inside of a waterfall function, using the async library, including various operations such as:
[...]
- create a database entry for a new author
- create a database entry for a new book
- associate the new book to an author (reference to book ID)
[...]

This is the method called by my route, which handles the associated POST-request:

```
exports.createAuthor = function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.url+' !!!POST REQUEST INCOMING!!! '+req.body);

    async.waterfall([

        function(callback){
            //create Author db entry
        },

        function(parameter, callback){
            //add author to additional directory (db action)
        },

        function(parameter, callback){
            //create book db entry
        },

        function(parameter, callback){
            //associate book to author (db action)
        }

    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log('DONE!!!');
        res.send('200');
    }); 
}
```

This is the client-side AngularJS controller code:

```
searchApp = angular.module("searchApp",[]);
searchApp.controller('authorCreator', function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.tags = [];

    $scope.sendAuthor = function(){  

    alert('I was called!');    
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/newauthor/',
        data: { 'authorname' : $scope.authorName,
                'authordescription' : $scope.authorDescr, 
                'bookname' : $scope.bookName, 
                'tags' : $scope.tags }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            //no actions yet
        })
        .error(function(){
            //no actions yet
        });
    };
});
```

This is the AngularJS form:

```
<div ng-controller="authorCreator">
    <form>
        <p>Author name: <input ng-model="authorName"></p>
        <p>Author description: <input ng-model="authorDescr"></p>
        <p>Book name: <input ng-model="bookName"></p>
        <p>Tags:<input ng-model="tags"></p>
        <p><button ng-click="sendAuthor()">Send</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I noticed that, if the waterfall-process is "stuck" somewhere, meaning the client does not get an answer to it's request whatsoever, the POST request seems to be sent a second time automatically (as soon as the browser is giving a timeout according to firebug). According to firebug, a second POST request does not seem to be sent by the browser, so the call must be initiated from somewhere else. 
I found out by checking the database (multiple documents with identical values, except the ObjectID of course) and monitoring the node.js console window where I output incoming POST data. Again: as soon as the entire waterfall-process completes, hence the client browser does not abort the post request after a while, and res.send('200') executes, the error does not occur (= no multiple db entries).
Can anyone please tell me, who does initiate this second POST request and how may I deactivate it?
Cheers

Igor

Comment: relevant code please, client and server side

Comment: Did you also verify this "second request" by more reliable means, such as your browser's developer tools' network tab or by adding a log statement at the start of a request handler?

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on that issue I found out, that this error seems to be based on missing answers to the client (be it via res.json, res.sendfile, ...). Therefore the client seems to re-send the request after some time, thus executing server-side code a second time. Responding to the client in reasonable time solves this issue. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you heard of any way to stop client from sending twice the request and be able to keep the connection stilll open ?

Comment: Errr no. That's not what I was working with here. I am using a serversside API on a per request base. I am not using persistent connections here...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:

```
exports.createAuthor = function(req, res) {
if(req.method == 'POST' && req.url = 'REQUESTEDURL'){
    console.log('POST REQUEST INCOMING!!! '+req.body);
    async.waterfall([
      //TODO...
    ]);
}
```

Maybe the problem is that the favicon or some other resource is doing a request to

Comment: I added this to my code. Same error. Both times the output for req.url was /newauthor/.
Firebug just says "aborted" at a certain point but a second POST request does not seem to be sent. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added the exact same if-statement from above (without replacing REQUESTEDURL with /newauthor/). I added an additional console.log statement prior to the if-statement showing req.url. Now, no data is written to the db, still I get two POST requests by "/newauthor/". Or what else do you mean by "adding the same code"?

Comment: `console.log(req.url)` and check the name of the request

Comment: That's what I did. The output remains: "/newauthor/".

Comment: Hmmm, then, can you check if the `$scope.sendAuthor` is executed 2 times (with an `alert` or `console.log`) to verify if is the node method or if is the angular scope

Comment: I added an alert message at the beginning of the sendAuthor() method. I only get one alert, therefore it seems, that there is no second data sending on the client side.

Comment: What is executed 2 times, only the `async.waterfall` or the console.log message too?

Comment: The console.log message prior to the async.waterfall as well as the async.waterfall process to the point where it got stuck the first time. It seems, exports.createAuthor is being called twice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice

Comment: Thanks for that, but as I said: 
1) According to Firebug, no second POST request is fired by the browser (hence no outgoing JSON data a second time).
2) I added an alert at the beginning of the AngularJS sending code and the alert message always just appears once.
:(

Comment: Try fiddler to check if the problem is on your front-end or your backend. If appears two times in fiddler, then your problem is in the front-end http://www.telerik.com/fiddler [1] [1]:http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

i "fixed" this by adding

```
 .get('/favicon.ico:1', (req, res) =>{
//do nothing because i dont care
  })
```