# controller getting called twice due to append params in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am in angularjs. I am trying to append paramter in url using `$location.search('sid', key);`. The value of key is coming from another server by http request. 
Here is the code for append parameter.

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'test1.html',
                controller: 'test1Controller'
            })
            .when('/message/:userId', {
                templateUrl: 'test2.html',
                controller: 'test2Controller'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }])
.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location' ,'getAuthDetails', function($route, $rootScope, $location,getAuthDetails) {
        var key;

        getAuthDetails.get().then(function(data){
            key = data.key;
            $rootScope.query = 'sid='+key;
            console.log($location.$$path);
            $location.search('sid', key);  //append parameter. This is calling controller twice
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            $rootScope.query = 'sid='+key;
        });
    }]);
```

The problem i am having is . As the sid get append in url. The `console.log` i put in `test1Controller` getting called twice. Sid is used to connect with socket connection.

Is there any workaround to call the controller after the url append.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reloadOnSearch: false`

Example:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'test1.html',
                controller: 'test1Controller',
                reloadOnSearch: false // wont reload the controller when the search query changes
            })
            .when('/message/:userId', {
                templateUrl: 'test2.html',
                controller: 'test2Controller'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }])
```

Comment: @Neil There are lots of small features that are hidden in angular that even the angular docs dont provide it with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are writing controller only once. write either in ng-controller or in your config route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',
        { 
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
            //Remove controller from here
        });
    }]);
```

**home.html**

```
<!-- Add the ng-controller in your view -->
<div ng-controller="MyItemsController">
    <!-- Your stuff -->
</div>
```

Try using  `reloadOnSearch`: false inside your config it will prevent controller from loading.

Comment: I only use this in index file . <body ng-app="myApp">

<div id="views" ng-view></div>

Comment: I think the delay due the http request is causing the problem. But not sure