# Why ng-table get data api request sent two times?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to get data's leave details from server. When I click or reload the link (http://localhost/portal/getleaves) api request send two times in firebug.

Sample code attached here:

```
    $http.get('/portal/api/leave/'+id).
    success(function(data) {
        var data = data.result;
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,           // count per page
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
              $defer.resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: I also faced this issue before. Please add  from where you are calling this & make sure controller should execute only once(whether from state or html - ngController).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably one of the following:

1) [Your entire controller is being executed twice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice)

2) You aren't actually sending out 2 GET requests. If you are doing CORS requests an [OPTIONS request will be sent](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) before the GET request is sent.