# fetching data twice angular factory in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a factory to make GET requests to social media APIs. This is working fine, and showing the data in the views, however when I inspect in the console it makes the `GET` request twice, for each individual `GET` request. This means that at times it displays the data twice in the front end.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I imagine it may be to do with the way I am implementing the factory.

See code below. If there is anything else that needs to be clarified please let me know. Thanks!

**factory**

```
app.factory('socialMedia', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      fetchFlickr: function() {
        var self = this;
        return $http.jsonp("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=sonymusic&tagmode=alll&format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK");
      },

      fetchTwitter: function() {
        return $http({
          url: 'get_tweets.php',
          method: 'GET'
        })
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**App controller**

```
app.controller("testCtrl", ["$routeParams", "truncateFilter","socialMedia", function ($routeParams, socialMedia) {

    testCtrl = this;
    this.twitterPosts = [];
    this.flickrPosts = [];
    this.loading = true;

    socialMedia.fetchTwitter().success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            testCtrl.twitterPosts.push(data[i]);
        }        
    })
    .error(function () {
        test.loading = false;
        test.error = true;
    });

     //call to get the data from Flickr
    socialMedia.fetchFlickr().success(function (data) {
        var x = data.items.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
            test.flickrPosts.push(data.items[i]);
        }
        test.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function () {
        test.loading = false;
        test.error = true;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Check that you're not calling the controller twice. Btw, if you use `ui-router`, those services can be [resolved](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combating AngularJS executing controller twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice)

Comment: @soyuka that was it! thanks