# Angular Controller getting loaded multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page application with one root html and rest of the functionality divided in multiple pages.
In my root controller I have some functionality where I register for callback from one service for getting few notifications.

But somehow when I load some of the pages my root controller is getting loaded two/three times  and because of that my callbacks are not getting called which are registered in service.

So How can I prevent my controller getting loaded multiple times.
I don't have control over routing as I am using Angular Kenod which takes care of routing.

Comment: You probably have `ng-controller="rootController"` or something similar in two or three places. This commonly happens when you have routing that instantiates the controller, but then in your view you also have `ng-controller`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice