# angular ui router: component $onInit fires twice on route change

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, components

I am using angular-ui-router 0.2.18 with angular 1.5.x. I cannot explain why my component $onInit fires twice (I do not think it is relevant to my problem, but I am also using webpack).

My routing:

```
myModule.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('app.project', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/project',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })

    .state('app.project.demo', {
        url: '/demo',
        template: '<my-component></my-component>'
    });

});
```

A barebone version of my component:

```
myModule.component('myComponent', {
    template: require('./my-component.html'),
    bindings: {},
    controller: function () {

        this.alert = function () {
            console.log("fires");
        };

        this.$onInit = function () {
            this.alert();
        };

    }
});
```

Somewhere in my application, the route change is triggered by `<a ui-sref="app.project.demo"></a>`.

The `alert` function fires twice when I click the link, but not when I reload the page. Maybe the controller is loaded twice on route change ?

I have tried everything listed on this [SO question: combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice), but without success.

What really puzzles me though, is that the issue disappears when I rename my state name without changing anything else:

- `'app.project.demos'` works
- `'app.projects.demo'` works too (after changing `'app.project'` to `'app.projects'`of course)

What could be the explanation ?