# Controller called twice in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, controllers

I am using angular-routing in my code , for which following is the code Snippet.
**Problem** is that the main controller is being called twice. I have already taken care of not declaring it again in markup ( as advised everywhere). I suspect there's something wrong in my routing code.

```
    app.directive('routeLoadingIndicator', function ($rootScope,$timeout) {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.isRouteLoading = false;

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
            scope.isRouteLoading = true;
        });
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
            $timeout(function(){
                scope.isRouteLoading = false;                    
            }, 10);
        });
    }
};
});
```

HTML :

```
     <route-loading-indicator >
        <div  class="spinner" ng-if='isRouteLoading'>
            <div class="rectLoader"></div>                
        </div>
    <div class="right_col"  ng-if='!isRouteLoading' style="padding-top: 60px;"   ng-view>   
    </div>  </route-loading-indicator>
```

Controller :

```
   app.controller('main',   function($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope){
    console.log("main Controller");
  });
```

Routing Code :

```
   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "xyz.html",
        controller : "main"
    })
  });
```

Comment: can you recreate the issue in a fiddle

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. Include all the necessary stuff, and exclude all the irrlevant stuff (like your routeLoadingIndicator).

Comment: The code is working fine. check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/c8u34s37/

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice) ?

Comment: why do you have an `ng-if` on same element as `ng-view`?

Comment: @charlietfl, because I want to display the content conditional to the variable isRouteLoading

Comment: @EbinManuval , Yes now that I see your fiddle , it works. But locally it does'nt. Not sure why , but anyway , it's resolved by ng-show directive. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Another simple way is `ng-class`. Need to realize that `ng-if` both removes the `ng-view` not enabling angular to populate it and  also creates needless child scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes right because of

```
<div class="right_col"  ng-if='!isRouteLoading' style="padding-top: 60px;"   ng-view>
```

this code as on route change event of **$routeChangeStart** and **$routeChangeSuccess** you togging value Hence **ng-if** get called twice as well your

> ng-view

Remove ng-if from ng-view directive can help you...

In my way::: you should go with show and hide directive....
Like this::

```
<div class="right_col"  ng-show='!isRouteLoading' style="padding-top: 60px;"   ng-view>
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it works because using ng-show does not recreate the directive's elements, but hide/show them. When angular recreate the div element (using ng-if) your controller get called again.