# Refreshing a view resolves everything twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two problems with `ui-router` state transition:

- When transitioning from a parent state to a child state, the parent state is resolved again, which I think should not happen. This happens only when transitioning the first time, all other times it works as expected.
- If user refreshes the page using browser refresh, the parent states are resolved twice. I understand that the parent state would resolve if I refresh a child state. But that should resolve once. It is resolving twice.

The code that I am using:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("root.test", {
    abstract: true,
    url     : "/abc",
    template: '<ui-view/>'
  })
.state("root.test.edit", {
    url  : "/:testId",
    views: {
      "@": {
        template  : require('../edit.html'),
        controller: "TestEditController"
      }
    },
    params: {
      testObject: {value: null}
    },
    redirectTo: 'root.test.edit.select',
    resolve: {
      testObject: function () {
        console.log('test object resolved');
      }
    }
  })
.state("root.test.edit.select", {
    url  : "/select",
    views: {
      "main@root.test.edit": {
        template  : require('../select.html'),
        controller: "TestEditSelectController"
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      selectObject: function () {
        console.log('select object resolved');
      },
    }
})
.state("root.test.edit.select.dialogBox", {
    params: {
      testObject: {value:null}
    },
    resolve: {
      testObject: function () {
        console.log('dialog box opens');
      },
    },
    onEnter: ['$state', '$uibModal',
      function ($state, $uibModal) {
        $uibModal.open({
          template  : require('../dialogBox.html'),
          controller: 'DialogBoxController',
          resolve   : {
            testObject: function () {
              return testObject;
            }
          }
        }).result.then(function (testObject) {
          $state.go('root.test.edit.select', { testObject: testObject}, {reload: true});
        }, function () {
          $state.go('root.test.edit.select');
        }
      );
      }]
})
```

For the first problem mentioned above:

If I am in `root.test.edit.select` state and when I click on a button to open a dialog box which is the state `root.test.edit.select.dialogBox`, `test object resolved` -> `select object resolved` -> `dialog box opens` everything is printed on the console, meaning all parents are resolved. But when I close the dialog box and open it again, only `dialog box opens` is printed, which is how it should be even when opening the dialog box for the first time.

For the second problem mentioned above:

If I am in `root.test.edit.select` state and I refresh the page using browser button, `test object resolved` -> `select object resolved` -> `test object resolved` -> `select object resolved` is printed i.e. both parent and child are resolved twice.

I checked for my mistakes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535336/combating-angularjs-executing-controller-twice#15535724), but everything is fine according to that post.

Comment: It could be a result of your non-standard redirectTo functionality or the `$state.$go` in your `onEnter` handler. By design, the router will only execute resolves once and only if the state is not already active.

Comment: @JCFord Why is it a non-standard functionality? Can you let me know any way to circumvent this?

Comment: My mistake. `redirectTo` is a built-in feature of ui-router 1.0. In any case, comment out the redirection and state transition code. Pare the state config down to the minimum and then start re-adding features while you keep an eye on the resolve behavior. That's how you can track it down.