# Angularjs: Controller is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

For some reason, my controller is double called, when I switch between resource 1 and resource2.

Here's the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="multiple_calls">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="#res/1">1</a>
    <a href="#res/2">2</a>

    <div ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('multiple_calls', []);

app.
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/res/:id', {templateUrl: 'res.html',
                        controller: 'res'
      });
}]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('res', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log('resource called')
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
});
```

**res.html**

```
{{id}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HsCJmbllOcnlvlc1oiHa?p=preview

If you click item 1 and then 2, you'll see that "resource called" is printed 3 times: 2 times for each change between resources.

Any clues why this happens?

Answer (score 14):

Found an exact same question:

[AngularJs: controller is called twice by using $routeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442954/angularjs-controller-is-called-twice-by-using-routeprovider)

The solution is to add "/" at the end of router url:

```
-      when('/res/:id',
+      when('/res/:id/',
```

Comment: This also fixed my problem. However, I'm defining my routes with `$stateProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

This also works if you change to angular version 1.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning angular and I have experienced this problem, when I wrote the directive and included controllers.

I hope will help someone as I spent quite some time to see what I did:

```
.directive("list", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: "contacts/list",
    controller: "CMSController", //- not needed at all
    controllerAs: 'cCtrl'//- not needed at all
  };
})

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   ....
    .when('/CMS', {
      templateUrl: 'contacts/index',
      controller: 'CMSController',
      controllerAs: 'cCtrl',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

one another solution which worked for me is that if you defined a directive, try not set its controller to the one which is calling multiple times, just add the directive to your app by using `app.directive`.

```
    app.directive('myDirective',[ '$window', function ($window) {
    function link(scope, element) {
           // stuff
        });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {offset: "@"},
      link: link,
      // controller: myCtrl //myCtrl was called multiple I comment this line
    };
  }]);
```