# AngularJS controller is being called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I new in AngularJS. I am learning AngularJS. I am trying to follow different tutorials. I working with some codes now. I have a question in this regard. My codes ares as below

index.html

```
<html ng-app="main_app">
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">   
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="main_controller">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

route.js

```
var app = angular.module('main_app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider)
{
   $routeProvider

   // route for the home page
   .when('/', {
               templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
               controller  : 'main_controller'
            });
});

app.controller('main_controller', function($scope) 
{
    alert('Yes');        
});
```

If I run this code I get the `alert('Yes');` twice.

Why I am getting this alert twice ??  Is it normal action or I am doing something wrong ??

Thanks

**Update**

**@Leo Farmer** I changed structure of *index.html* as belows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">   
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="main_app">
            <div ng-controller="main_controller">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

But still I am getting **alert()** twice. Actually my concern is "Am I doing wrong or right ??" I think getting **alert()** twice means I am doing something wrong.

Is my structure following good convention ??

Thanks

Comment: the controller can fire any number of times, so it's not a good place for an alert()...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis for your reply. Why **any number of times** ?? How can I control this **any number of times** ?? Thanks

Comment: to be clearer: anything that happens that's attached to the controller will fire it, it's not a one-time "load()"-style event. you can not recycle it, which would solve your particular problem, but it's good to understand why it's an issue in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: controller is called twice by using $routeProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442954/angularjs-controller-is-called-twice-by-using-routeprovider)

Answer (score 6):

Your controller is getting called twice. You have it in your body element (that's alert number one) then you also assign it as your controller for your pages/home.html which you call as your partial (that's alert two).

You don't need it in your body element. I recommend you take it out of there.

Comment: My up vote +1  for exact solution  `You don't need it in your body element. I recommend you take it out of there`

Comment: Update: You don't need to add ng-controller="main_controller" to your div as you are adding the controller in your $routeProvider. You only need to call it in one place.

Comment: This was the answer in my case, after removing that on my body it went away. Thanks!!!!

Comment: 6 years later, the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have used `<div id="userregistration" class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="UserRegistrationController">` in html and in `$route` also so it called twice. I removed in html after that it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend modifying your alert code so it is triggered by a button or another event. You're seeing the asynchronous calling of a controller that, due to the times of which loading and processing your page, causes that code to be run twice.

I would first try loading your Javascript at the bottom of your body so that the entire page is loaded before JavaScript is.

Alternatively, you could try adding a timeout using the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service to delay running your alert for a short time until the entire page loads.

Comment: Thanks @bman4789. That means once at the time of loading and another at the time of processing ?? Thanks

Comment: This is mostly BS. The controller is not called multiple times in the usual case. It's called twice here because it's specifically (although unintentionally) instructed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

1. You are using same controller in anguler route module and ng-controller directive in the template. If you use a controller in the route module while configuring, it is useless to use same controller with ng-controller in the template. ng-view directive is enough here.
2. Since you are using same controller both in route config and ng-controller, thats why you are getting alert twice. You should use your controller either in angular  route or ng-controller directive
3. If you remove routing option, you will get alert only once.